# C++/CLR write data from port in file

Tags: fstream, serial-communication

I established a port-communication that logs some data from the serial port in an text field.
The communication is successful an the text is displayed in the textfield.

Next, I would like to write the data in a file. The general writing in a file works well, but how can I convert the received data, that it is compatible with fstream?

I tried the following.
Writing in a textArea is working. The fstream connection with a test-string is working, as well. But the problem is in line fs<<ReceivedData, because of incompatible types:

```
    //Write Data in a textArea
    tbData->AppendText(sp->ReadLine()+"\n");

    //Write Data in a file
    String^ ReceivedData = sp->ReadLine();
    std::fstream fs;
    fs.open("data.txt", std::fstream::out);
    
    fs << ReceivedData;

    fs.close();
```

Comment: [Write a Text File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/file-handling-and-i-o-cpp-cli?view=msvc-170#write_text)